# Copy and paste content of row in a cell of a different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to excel vba, so i am sorry if the solution is easy

The following code is what i have until now:

```
Set wbExcel = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSheet1 = wbExcel.Sheets(1)
Set wsSheet2 = wbExcel.Sheets(2)
MyString = "xxx"
Set rng = wsSheet2.Range("A1:A10") 
On Error Resume Next
For Each row In rng
    If Mid(row, 1, 3) = MyString Then
        Dim content
        content = row
        wsSheet1.Cells("B4") = content
        End
    End If
Next row
End Sub
```

I tried to copy a special cell in a worksheet into another cell of a worksheet.
Obviously the range(A1:A10) contains what i am searching for with the for each loop.
It looks like that the If-loop is working. It just does not copy anything
Also I do not know if I have to use the variable "row" as Object or as Range.
I hope that you guys can help me understand this.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Partially Matching Strings (Begins With)

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyStringsBeginsWith()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source (read from)
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(2)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1:A10")
    
    ' Destination (write to)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dws.Range("B4")
    
    ' Loop and copy.
    
    Dim scell As Range, sStr As String
    
    For Each scell In srg.Cells
        sStr = CStr(scell.Value)
        If InStr(1, sStr, "xxx", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            dcell.Value = sStr
            Set dcell = dcell.Offset(1) ' next destination row (cell)
        End If
    Next scell
    
    ' Clear below.
    dcell.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - dcell.Row + 1).Clear
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Strings copied.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `On Error Resume Next` is hiding the fact that the line `wsSheet1.Cells("B4") = content` is not valid, it results in an error which is 'hidden' because of the use of `On Error Resume Next`. Change the line to `wsSheet1.Range("B4") = content` (ie replace `Cells` with `Range`) and, I suggest, delete `On Error Resume Next`.

You can read more about using the Worksheet.Cells property [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells) and about using the Worksheet.Range property [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.range).

You can also tidy-up / simplify the `For Each` loop as follows

```
For Each Row In Rng
    If Mid(Row.Value, 1, 3) = MyString Then
        wsSheet1.Range("B4") = Row.Value
        End
    End If
Next Row
```

And, for info, `Row` is a Range. You can define it (`Dim` it) as Object but Range is more specific.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will look at the links you shared with me for better understanding

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the check mark next to it. This helps keep the focus on older questions which still don't have answers.